# Reputation changes

Tags: discussion, reputation

I think I've asked this before, but don't remember the answer.  My reputation dropped 10 points today.  IIRC, that is because someone who contributed to my total in the past no longer is on the forum, so I lose the points he gave me.  Not a great plan, but them's the rules.

Question:  Is there any way to find out either who it was, or the thread that was devalued?

ak

Comment: Yeah I lost 30 points today but, it's done now. Forget it.

Comment: +1 it's not obvious (to me) why this question gets meta downvotes. "Inquiring minds want to know".

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot find out, all you get to see are the consequences.

IIRC, when they remove a user, there is a choice to allow points to be removed or kept but they look at "the greater good" and decide as appropriate.

Also, as far as I have understood as I have asked this on other stacks, even Moderators don't get to see that detail easily - has to be some request or other.

Answer (score 2):

If the user was low rep, they take the points away. If they were high rep (if I remember right, 6000+ rep) then they leave it.

The rep can't be tracked